# Why is caught Exception getting logged in the console while executing unit test with JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit4

I am a newbie in JUnit and i am trying to write unit test for the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    public void throwException() throws MyException {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.getString("param");
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            throw new MyException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My use case is such that i can only throw MyException (my wrapper around the Exception class) from the throwException() method. I have written a test case for this using JUnit as follows:

```
@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public void testIfThrowsException throws MyException {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.throwException();
}
```

When i run this unit test case, the test is passed but still JSONException is getting logged in the console. Console Message:

```
- param parameter is not string
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["param"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:498)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:669)
    at .......
```

Is this the expected behavior or am i doing something wrong in the implementation of the unit test. If this is expected then how can i suppress such a console message.

Comment: Syntactically the throws keyword cannot be applied at class level, only at the method level. Also, your method name, testIfThrowsException should have brackets.

Comment: @isakgilbert sorry that was a typo, corrected that.

Comment: Post your code, line numbers and the whole stack trace.  Is your myClass constructor `new MyClass()` possibly throwing the exception?

Comment: @mikeb you should take a closer look at the question... The error **is** expected. That's what the OP's testing.

Comment: @mikeb: that was my thought too, but the `JSONException` isn't being passed to `MyException`, and the stack trace would appear to be that from the caught `JSONException`

Comment: @aribeiro - You should read the code and understand that my comment is correct, and likely what is happening.

Comment: @beresfordt - The exception not being passed to `MyException` does not mean a thing.  The `throwException` method **can't** throw an `JSONException`, so it must be coming from somewhere else.  That's why I asked for more code.

Comment: @mikeb, I didn't mean to be rude. What I meant is that the OP's purposely throwing the exception. The method `throwException` is being explicitly called and, as the name states, is throwing an exception on purpose: `json.getString("param")` on an empty JSON object.

Comment: @aribeiro - Right, I can see what he's doing.  The `JSONException` will be caught, and `MyException` thrown.  The exception he is getting, therefore, is not coming from that method, since it's not possible for that method to throw a `JSONException`  The only other place it could be coming from is the `new MyClass()` bit, or he has left out something significant.

Comment: @mikeb, I agree with you. Something must be missing.

Comment: Are you sure that's your actual code that's failing? It works for me 'as expected' - i.e. no exception is logged. Are you sure that the JSONException isn't being logged by something in your exception handler before it throws MyException?

Comment: @sisyphus you are right the constructor of the MyException was causing the log message. Sorry i was so fixated on my own code that i did not bother to check implementation of MyException before.